# How to get active minutes from Google-Fit

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am trying to find a way to get the active minutes of a user. I already found out how to get number of steps, calories, ect. for a given timespan, but it would be nice if it would also tell me the number of active minutes during those buckets... is that somehow possible?

Comment: I suggest you to check the [Google Fit Android documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/) for the Data types that you can get by using this API. You will learn here the things that you can only do or possible with the API. Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types#public_data_types) for the data types that you can see in this documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I know this might be a little late, but since it might help other people. Assuming that you already know how to build up your request and are able to get access to your buckets. Each of the buckets has a value 'startTime' and 'endTime' you should be able to get your active time for all your activities by subtracting the start time from the end time. Something like the code below should help:

```
for (Bucket bucket : result.getBuckets()) {
    long activeTime = bucket.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MINUTES) - bucket.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    totalActiveTime = totalActiveTime + activeTime;

    Log.i(TAG, "Total active time: " + totalActiveTime);        
}
```

Hope this will still help anyone!